# Shared database options in scrum team

Tags: sql-server-2008, replication, shared, scrum

I have a broad question I would like some advice on.

I'm a developer on a 3-person scrum team working on the same application (c# web form application).  For years, the process has been that developers run a local IIS site on their machine and point their application at a shared database.  Using the shared database has many benefits over local SQL instances for our business and minimizes the overhead for each developer on setup and maintenance.

This process has worked for years (mainly because everyone was in the office), but now half of us work from home or remotely.  SQL performance through the VPN is atrocious, and ends up slowing our local sites down at an order of magnitude when processing the SQL calls through the VPN.    Because of the slowness, it's really caused slowed down my productivity and I'm looking for options.

I've thought of the following solutions:

1. Run SQL locally

   - Setup Replication
   - Try and point a SQL instance at a UNC path for mdl files (if this is possible)
2. Tweak VPN settings to speed up MS-SQL calls

   - I'm doubtful there is a way to speed up the traffic going through the VPN, but       I'd be open to any ideas.
3. RDP into my machine at work when I work from home.  I truly hate doing this.

Below are the technical specs of our setup:

1. MS-SQL 2008 R2
2. C# Web Forms

   - N-Tier Architecture

Have any other development teams had this issue before, if so what where some of the solutions?

Thanks

Comment: When I work from home, I RDP to my machine at work.  This has some benefits (and I suppose a few drawbacks), but it works for me.  Just curious...why do you hate this option?

Comment: Well, most of the time when the connection is good, i don't see typing lag.  However, probably a couple 2-3 times per day (for whatever reason) the connection will slow down and get choppy and laggy - drives me crazy.  If the connection was always great, I think think a VDI or RDP solution might be OK.

Comment: Yeah, a slow connection is probably the biggest drawback.  I've been fortunate in that regard.  So if you pursue option 1 and run SQL locally, what issues will you have?  Is SQL already installed locally?  Would you need to "synch" data from your office on a regular basis?  How big is the database?

Comment: Running option 1 would introduce some different issues.  The first thing is that it's a lot more overhead me (and other dev's) to install MS-SQL.  However, i considered taking the entire virtual hard disk and mounting it on my machine and running it local.  The next thing I would have to do is somehow get replication working from the office SQL to my local machine.  This could difficult - i've never done it.  The db i'm using is less than 100MB - not that big.

Comment: As a dba, installing MSSQL Dev Edition (or Express) isn't that big of a deal for me.  However, if there are any differences in server-level settings, you may develop code that works locally, but doesn't run "in the office" (or vice-versa).  I agree that 100MB is not that big.  Is replication a must?  Could you synch the data via a backup/restore on a daily or weekly basis?

Comment: I could do a backup/restore but wouldn't I lose all the data I authored on my local SQL everything I run the job?  Or is there a way to do a merge?

Comment: Yes, you would lose everything locally in the db whenever you restored a backup "from the office".  What would the "data I authored" be?  [DML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff848766(v=sql.105).aspx) or [DDL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff848799(v=sql.105).aspx)?  Or both?

Comment: Potentially any updated SPROCS, data scripts and data that got added through the application running locally on my machine would be overriden by the "From the office" copy.

Comment: In my past dev life, things like SP's (and other db objects) were scripted out and put in source control for the benefit of other developers.  When ready to deploy the software, the scripts were run in a specific sequence against the target/production database.  Do you do something similar? If so, those changes would be maintained outside of the db...As for your data changes, is it really necessary to merge them back to the "office" db?  I guess you could script out those data changes too, but that seems to defeat the purpose of your development.  I'm not sure how to advise you on that.

Comment: We script out everything and the files live in Source Control.  This includes but not limited to data upgrade scripts, table scripts, sprocs, udf's, triggers, index, etc.

Comment: From a DBA perspective, I've heard that SQL 2012 has new features that allow scaling of the database, and multiple DB's setup with designated "READONLY" and "WRITE ONLY" status.  How hard would that be to have a "READONLY" copy running locally, and they "WRITE" copy lives as the shared Database?  Conceptually the "READONLY" copies just get the updates when they are committed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regardless of the technology you are using, this situation happens to many developers who work remotely.

Your three options are viable but consider this:

1. Running a local database server introduce the possibility of environmental errors. If you have 3 developers, you now have 3 different databases. Even if the structure of the DB itself never changes, the test data will certainly differ from one developer to the other. At some point you may have to reconcile the "master" version of the test data with each local instances.
2. Tweaking the VPN settings is certainly worth looking into but I cannot help you with that. I have no idea how you would do this.
3. RDP into your remote machine could be the best option. This will guarentee you have the same setup when you work from home or from the office. I worked in two different large companies before and that's how we were doing it in both places. May I ask why you hate this? It's true sometimes it doesn't work or it is very slow.

You may end up doing all these options. I mean tweaking your network speed is always good, no matter how your work. You could have local instances on which you do your development then you synchronize your work with the repository and RDP to your office machine to test your new code with the master instance of the database. This way you don't have to work on RDP all day and you end-up testing your code twice, in two different environments. That's good, right?

Comment: thanks for the input.  I wish there was a silver bullet solution for the problem :)

Question for you.  When you've done RDP in the past has it always been done via VPN, or did they expose a public endpoint for the RPD?